# AngluarJS - ng-options with nested arrays (conditional optgroup)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options, optgroup

I have this (simplified) data:

```
[{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Option (WITHOUT SubValues) - should be selectable",
    "SubValues": []
},
{
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "Option (WITH SubValues)",
    "SubValues": [{
            "Id": "2-1",
            "Name": "SubValue - should be selectable"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2-2",
            "Name": "SubValue2 - should be selectable"
        }
    ]
}]
```

And using ng-options:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select ng-model="myType" class="form-control" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in data.d">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is:

- If an option *doesn't* have any `SubValues` - that should be selectable.
- If an option *does* have `SubValues` - that should become an
  '`optgroup`' and a SubValue would be selectable.

Maybe something like:

```
<select ng-model="myType" class="form-control" ng-options="item.Id as item.SubValues[1].Name group by item.Name for item in data.d">
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waynejf/tr0c942j/) that hopefully makes it clearer.

Is this possible with the current structure? If not what is the best way to achieve it?